# Sync ObservableCollection in ViewModel to ObservableCollection (of same type) in Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I currently have a couple of Model objects as follows:

```
public class ModelBaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Members omitted for brevity, but there is a DateTime property
    //that becomes important further down (see dummy method in application controller)      
}
```

and another:

```
public class ModelCollectionClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass> modelBaseClasses;
    public ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass> ModelBaseClasses
    {
        get { return modelBaseClasses; }
        set
        {
            modelBaseClasses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelBaseClasses");
        }
    }

    private void modelBaseClasses_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelBaseClasses"));
    }
}
```

Then in one of my view's view-model, I have observable collections like such:

```
private ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass> modelBaseClasses;
public ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass> ModelBaseClasses
{
    get{ return modelBaseClasses ?? (modelBaseClasses = new ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass>()); }
    set
    {
        modelBaseClasses = value;                
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelBaseClasses"));
    }
}    

private ObservableCollection<ModelCollectionClass> modelCollectionClasses;
public ObservableCollection<ModelCollectionClass> ModelCollectionClasses
{
        get { return modelCollectionClasses ?? (modelCollectionClasses = new ObservableCollection<ModelCollectionClass>()); }
        set
        {
            modelCollectionClasses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelCollectionClasses"));                
        }
 }
```

Then in my application controller (delegates work to view-models), I have a dummy method that loads up the ModelBaseClass collection like follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    myViewModel.ModelBaseClasses.Add(new ModelBaseClass()
    {
       DateTimeProperty = Convert.ToDateTime("06/2" + i + "/2012 09:00:00 AM")
       //Other properties get set as well, using the i variable...
    }
}
```

It should be noted that there are more than one for loops in this method so that I can have plenty of data to work with.

Next, I have a method that takes that large collection of objects and groups them by date like follows:

```
myViewModel.ModelBaseClasses
                .GroupBy(modelBaseClass => ((DateTime)modelBaseClass.DateTimeProperty).Date)
                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(
                    list => myiewModel.ModelBaseCollections.Add(new ModelBaseCollection() { ModelBaseClasses = new ObservableCollection<ModelBaseClass>(list) })
                );
```

Now this is where it starts getting more intricate.  In the XAML of my view, I have an ItemsControl declared with its ItemsSource bound to the ModelCollectionClasses property in my view-model.  It looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ModelCollectionClasses, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyView}}}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}">                    
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then in a resource dictionary for this particular view, I have a DataTemplate declared like follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsTemplate">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ModelBaseClasses}">            

        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedModelBaseClass, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:MyView}}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                

            <DataGrid.Columns>                                          
                    ...Omitted for brevity...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>            
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, with all of that said, I'm getting the desired visual representation of the data that I initially wanted.  However, the issue I'm now running into is when I want to delete one of the ModelBaseClass objects.  Because the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is being bound to the ModelBaseClasses property of the ModelCollectionClass, and not the ModelBaseClasses in my view-model, then when I remove a ModelBaseClass from the ModelCollectionClass found in my view-model I need to somehow notify the ModelCollectionClass of this change as well so that the UI will properly update.

I have seen a couple of other examples where some people have created wrapper classes to sync model collections and view-model collections, but I am having a tough time trying to implement such a thing with my own application.  Any insight or helpful hints/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that somebody will parse this big bunch of code for you? Try to be laconic.

Comment: I know it's quite a bit of code, but I'm trying to be as transparent as possible.  Thanks for looking however.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how you delete a ModelBaseClass, but if i guess right then you should raise a NotifyPropertyChanged there for your ModelBaseClass and ModelCollectionClass too.

Comment: BigL - Currently in one of my DataTemplateColumns I have specified a button that has its Command property bound to a Delete Command.  Then in the Executed method of that Command I do something like:


   myViewModel.MyBaseClasses.Remove(myViewModel.SelectedBaseClass);


But since the DataGrid is not bound to myViewModel.MyBaseClasses then the UI doesn't update, therefore my need to be able to notify all of the MyBaseCollection collections of that CollectionChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your question so complicated that I not sure that I get what you want to do. But I've noticed one thing in your code: in `ModelCollectionClass` you set `ModelBaseClass` property but notify that you set `ModelBaseClasses` (**es**). Not sure that it help.

Comment: That was a typo.  Let me try to summarize: ModelCollectionClass has OC<ModelBaseClass> called ModelBaseClasses. MyViewModel has OC<ModelBaseClass> (also) called ModelBaseClasses and is filled manually in the application controller. MyViewModel OC<ModelCollectionClass> called ModelCollectionClasses and is filled in the application controller using ModelBaseClasses from viewmodel. I can remove ModelBaseClass objects from ModelBaseClasses in VM, but need to notify ModelBaseClasses in ModelCollectionClass of this change, since the UI is bound to it, NOT ModelBaseClasses in the viewmodel.